# Adding a specific quantity of the product to the cart in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a problem because I have no idea how to implement 'adding a specific amount of product to cart'.
Currently, after pressing the 'Add to cart' button, a single quantity of product is added.

I don't know how to relate to this in the view and the template.

I would like it to take the value given instead of 1.

```
cart_item.quantity += 1
```

**cart/views.py**

```
def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
                cart_id = _cart_id(request)
            )
        cart.save()
    try:
      cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
      if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
          cart_item.quantity += 1
      cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
      cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
                  product = product,
                  quantity = 1,
                  cart = cart
          )
      cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

**cart/models.py**

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id

class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CartItem'

    def sub_total(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

**templates/shop/product.html**

```
  <div class="float-right">
   <div class="float-left"> <input type="number" value="1" aria-label="Search" 
    class="form-control" style="width: 100px"> </div>
    <a class="btn send-click btn-md my-0 p"  href="{% url 'cart:add_cart' product.id %}">Add to Cart</a></div>
```

urls.py

```
app_name='cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
    path('full_remove/<int:product_id>/', views.full_remove, name='full_remove'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change to a form with post handling you can fetch the amount with inline JS. You need to adapt your url and your view to also accept the number of items.

```
<div class="float-right">
   <div class="float-left"> <input id="amount_field" type="number" value="1" aria-label="Search" 
    class="form-control" style="width: 100px"> </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='{% url \"cart:add_cart\" product.id %}'.concat("/",document.getElementById('amount_field').value);" >Add Items</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I added urls.py above. However, I still do not understand, in the CartItem model, I have to create 'amount_field'?

Comment: how about you use the quantity field?

Comment: if I understand correctly, I have to create columns, e.g. quantityAdd, instead of '1'. I'm assign quantity to quantityAdd, right?

Comment: No the input field should contain the number that you want to add.

Comment: I created in the quantityAdd model and I tried add name="quantityAdd" and  and assign 'quantityAdd' to cart_item.quantity in views.

Comment: I do not undersatnd your approach: if you add more items from the same product just increase the field quantitiy of your cart item.

Comment: I would like after entering the value of product quantity. It has been sent to the basket. With the given quantity.

Comment: `cart_item.quantity += 1` I mean this line.I would like it to take the value given instead of 1.